# CollapsingToolbarLayout center title not working

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am making collapsing animation with toolbar.
I found my toolbar title is not center  in title bar.

I tried with collapsedTitleGravity property.
But it is failed.

What is my error? 
I want someone to know why it is.

It is my code layout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:collapsedTitleGravity="center_horizontal"
            app:title="@string/activity_title_complete_request">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle9_1"
                android:id="@+id/profile_id"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="10dp">

            <include layout="@layout/fragment_commercial_check_list" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Thank you so much.

Comment: why don't you take another relative layout inside collapsing tollbar and set a gravity to that view

Answer (score 0):

You use margin to set center your title.But using margin you can not set center.Please check below code. i think your title will be center.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:collapsedTitleGravity="center_horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:background="@drawable/rectangle9_1"
            android:id="@+id/profile_id"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:text="Title"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <include layout="@layout/fragment_commercial_check_list" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

try change values of these attributes

```
 app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
 app:expandedTitleMarginStart="64dp"
```

and also add this

```
app:expandedTitleGravity="center_horizontal"
app:collapsedTitleGravity="center_horizontal"
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it is not working. As you can see, I want to see that  expand left is not center.